# How to get 'users must enter a user name and password to use this computer’ on Windows 10

Tags: windows

I am trying to setup auto in for windows 10. I find this http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=8

There should be a check box ‘Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer’ when I execute 'control userpasswords2', but I don't see that checkbox.

I have tried 'netplwiz', I don't see that checkbox too.

I find another link: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10. It has a method which modify registry in windows. I have tried that as well. But I still can't get autologin.  I have set AutoAdminLogon to 1 and added 'DefaultUser' and 'DefaultPassword', but after I reboot. the AutoAdminLogon reset to 0. And DefaultPassword was removed. Any idea why?

How can I setup autologin?

Thank you.

Comment: did You set the AutoAdminLogon with an administrator account?